# Filtering azure groups by createdDateTime using graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using the Microsoft Graph API. I was wondering whether or not filtering was supported on the createdDateTime property for the API groups:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=CreatedDateTime ge '2019-01-01T21:15:12Z'
```

Error Message:

> {
>     "error": {
>       "code": "BadRequest",
>       "message": "Invalid filter clause",
>       "innerError": {
>         "request-id": "xxxx",
>         "date": "2019-10-16T15:10:08"
>       }
>     }
>   }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10/18/2019

I have confirmed with Azure support engineer that filter is not supported on the createdDateTime property for the API groups.